# Why printf takes the last number printed?

Tags: c, printf

EDIT: I already knew that printf is not typesafe I am just looking for an explination about what exactly ocurred (I mean describe the undefined behavior).

Why if I print "7" in the second printf, the program prints 9.334354. I know that if I don't write 7.0, this won't be printed but Why does it take the first number writted instead?.

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()  
{  
    printf("%.2f\n", 9.334354);    
    printf("%.5f\n", 7);  
    printf("%03d\n", 9);  
    getchar();  
}
```

This is the output

```
    9.33
    9.33435
    009
```

Comment: What does your first printf show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [using printf to print out floating values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295066/using-printf-to-print-out-floating-values)

Answer (score 16):

Repeat this to yourself for two weeks once a night before going to bed:

**printf is not typesafe. printf is not typesafe. printf is not typesafe.**

The function will only work if you pass it an argument of the type that you promise. Everything else is undefined behaviour. You promise a `double` (via `%f`) but provide an `int` (the type of the literal `7`), so it's undefined behaviour. Shame on you.

(I did once [go into details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295066/using-printf-to-print-out-floating-values/7295097#7295097) to explain the actual output, in case you're interested.)

---

*Update:* Since you're interested in the explanation for this particular behaviour, here's the (relevant) assembly for that code on my x86/GCC4.6.2/-O3:

First the data sections:

```
.LC0:
        .long   1921946325
        .long   1076013872   // 0x 4022AB30 728E92D5 is the binary rep of 9.334354
.LC1:
        .string "%.2f\n"
.LC2:
        .string "%.5f\n"
.LC3:
        .string "%03d\n"
```

Now the code:

```
        fldl    .LC0              // load number into fp register
        fstpl   4(%esp)           // put 64-bit double on the stack
        movl    $.LC1, (%esp)     // first argument (format string)
        call    printf            // call printf

        movl    $7, 4(%esp)       // put integer VA (7) onto stack
        movl    $.LC2, (%esp)     // first argument (format string)
        call    printf            // call printf

        movl    $9, 4(%esp)       // put integer VA (9) onto stack
        movl    $.LC3, (%esp)     // first argument (format string)
        call    printf            // call printf
```

The reason you see what you see is simple now. Let's for a moment switch to full 17-digit output:

```
  printf("%.17f\n", 9.334354);
  printf("%.17f\n", 7);
```

We get:

```
9.33435399999999937
9.33435058593751243
```

Now let's replace the integer by the "correct" binary component:

```
 printf("%.17f\n", 9.334354);
 printf("%.17f\n", 1921946325);
```

And voila:

```
9.33435399999999937
9.33435399999999937
```

What happens is that the `double` occupies 8 bytes on the stack, of value `0x4022AB30728E92D5`. The integer only occupies 4 bytes, and as it happens, the *least significant* four bytes are overwritten, so the floating point value is still nearly the same. If you overwrite the four bytes with the same bytes that occur in the original float, then you get the exact same result.

I might add that it's pure luck that the most significant four bytes remain intact. In different circumstances, they might have been overwritten with something else. In short, "undefined behaviour".

Comment: Yes I already knew that printf is not typesafe, as I pointed out in the question, if I don't write 7.0, the printf("%f") won't work. I am just looking for an explination about Why does it read instead the 9.33435, Would it be probably  a pointer that keeps the address of the first parameter 'cause an error ocurred?

Comment: "I am just looking for an explination"  -- WHY? Such an explanation does you no good ... and no one here can give it to you, because its an artifact of the implementation of your C system. "Would it be probably ..." -- No, probably not.

Comment: Cause I like to understand the whole process and not to say "undefined behavior" just cause I don't want to investigate, ask and understand what's happening.

And I understand that sometimes an undefined behavior is that, undefined, but other times someone can give you a perspective or a hint about what is going on.

Comment: @user1030615: Well, we can only analyse some particular platform behaviour. It seems that the variadic argument for the floating point number resolves to a floating point register, while the interger argument is passed on the call stack. Because of the wrong format specifier, the second `printf()` call reads the data again from the floating point register, which still contains the previous value. I'll add my assembly to the post.

Comment: @user1030615: I got the answer now. Forget about registers, it's a purely stack-based reason. Editing...

Comment: +1 Nice explanation, this is what I was talking about.This is very helpful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong format specifiers. You're passing a float (which turns into a double) so `printf` is expecting 8 bytes on the stack, but you pass an `int`, which is 4 bytes. Write `7.0` and `9.0` to turn the literals into doubles. Or, as Daniel said in the comments, the optimiser could cause all sorts of weird behaviour to occur.

Comment: And on a 32-bit architecture, depending on your calling convention, a 32-bit `int` might be passed in a register instead of on the stack, so the values might not even overlap.  Or the optimizer might do any manner of strange thing.

Answer (score 2):

As Barry Brown hinted at, your 7 is overwriting 4 bytes of the 8-byte double previously stored on the stack.  Depending on which way the stack grows and the endianness of your doubles, the 7 might just be overwriting the least significant bits of the double's mantissa.  Consequently, the double on the stack is not actually identical to that in the previous call to printf(); it's just that the difference is not visible in the %.5f format.

Printf() is not strictly typesafe, but some compilers check the format statement against the arguments and will warn you if you do something like this.

Comment: And this is a perfect complement to Barry Brown's answer, indeed is kind of what is happening, I remove the .5 from the %f of the second printf and prints this: 9.33451 The 7 is overwriting the 4 less significative bytes of the double's mantisa. Before: 01010101100110000011 10010100011101001001011010101010 After: 01010101100110000011 00000000000000000000000000000111 Thank you Alex

Answer (score 1):

You're telling `printf` that you're passing it a `double` (because of the `f` format specifier) but you're actually passing it an int.  That's [undefined behavior](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior), and literally anything could happen.

Answer (score 1):

7 is an int, but printf is expecting the argument to be a float. The argument from the previous printf (9.334354) is still sitting on the stack and the 7 alone isn't big enough to overwrite it.

If you change the 7 to 7.0, it works correctly.

Comment: Ohh so is because the stack.

Thank you !!

Comment: That is *probably* the reason, but it's just speculation.

Comment: It's a theory that fits all the data.

Answer (score 0):

`7` is an integer.
`7.0` is a float/double.

`printf` isn't typesafe so it's expecting a double but you're passing it an integer. That means undefined behavior.