# Anomalous behavior of printf()?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using %f to print an integer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673503/using-f-to-print-an-integer-variable)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%f",9/5);
    return 0;   
}
```

Output: 0.000000

Can anyone explain the output of the above program ?

Shouldn't be the output of program be 1.000000 ?

Comment: Enable your compiler warnings, you should get informed that `printf` argument types don't match the format string.

Comment: Also if you want the output `1.000000` then use `(float)(9/5)`, seems that no answer mentioned that for some reason

Comment: @pb2q: It's not really a duplicate of that question. This one has two issues: `int` division yielding `int`, and passing the result to `printf` with `"%f"`. I'm not sure I've seen a question with that combination.

Comment: The OP is still aware of the int division, though. It does add an unnecessary layer if it's not thought to be part of the problem, yes.

Comment: @Kos: gcc gives auch warnings; do other compilers? And you might as well cast to `double`, since it will be promoted anyway.

Comment: @chris: A good point (that I just came back here to mention). Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

```
printf("%f",9/5);
```

This statement is **undefined behavior** because the argument has to be of type `double` and `9 / 5` is of type `int`.

Use `9 / 5.0` to have an argument of type `double` (and the correct floating division).

Answer (score 4):

`9/5` is of type `int`. Passing an `int` argument to `printf` with `"%f"` has undefined behavior.

Try `9.0/5.0` if you want `1.800000`, or `(double)(9/5)` if you want `1.000000`

Answer (score 3):

Why is this?

So 9 / 5 is obtained by dividing two integers -- and dividing two integers results in an integer value, 1. But, since it's an int, and the `%f` specified wants a float, this is undefined behavior.

Ps.: you probably want

```
9.0 / 5
```

or

```
9 / 5.0
```

or

```
9.0 / 5.0
```

Comment: Crashing would have been a *good* thing; it would have made it clear that there's a problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson and you actually gave me a -1 for this?

Comment: No, it wasn't me. That was just a comment on your answer, not a response to your comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson ah OK. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Re: *Shouldn't be the output of program be 1.000000 ?*

It would have been had your division resulted in a float value rather than an `int`. Since you tried to print an `int` with a  `%f` format specification, the result was *undefined* behavior.

More details:

There are two problems, related though:

1. You are getting an `int`eger result from your division, but
   trying format for a float value using `%f`
2. (Your question seems to imply you are aware of this) Integer
   division results in an *integer* which is why the `%f` format
   specifier isn't appropriate. When the format specifier and the
   argument don't match the behavior is *undefined*.

   To avoid an integer result, try:

   `9.0 / 5` or `9 / 5.0` or even `9.0 / 5.0`

   to get the result you were expecting and *then* the `%f` specifier will be appropriate and work as expected.

   Note that when you are doing integer division, the result will be another integer. If, however, at *least one* of the operands is a float, the other operand will be promoted to a float too and the division will result in a float value.

   With integer division you get truncation, which means the fractional part of the result is thrown away.

Comment: The output should be 1.0 if this would be an example of integer division, but the output is 0.0. That's because the %f format expects a double and he provides an int.

Comment: @Femaref Agreed, I was adjusting my answer as you were making your comment :)  .. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `9/5` is 1 and is type of integer. The fraction part is simply truncated. To achieve what you want, force the division to make floating point operations with `5.0/9` or `5/9.0` or `5.0/9.0` or `(float) 5/9`

When type of integer argument is bound with `%f`, then the behaviour is undefined.

This is stated in C99 standard Section 7.21.6.1 Paragraph 9. This paragraph is quoted below:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined. **If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: No. The output is 0.0, not 1.0. That's because he is trying to display an int with %f as the format.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple.
9 is integer and 5 is also integer. when integer will be divided by integer then the result will be 0 and it will be escalated to 0.00000 because you have used "%f" in printf()
If you want the correct result perform
9.0/5
Now you will for sure get the correct answer

Comment: How does this add anything new to the answers posted 20 minutes ago?

Comment: @Levon The answer is simple: Because the typing in SO is faster than the speed of light, new users can't follow this and obviously they answer BEFORE they realize that someone else has already answered ;)