# printf prints the float read by scanf instead of the integer parameter

Tags: c, printf

The following program is supposed to read a float, then prints an integer. But when I run it, it doesn't print the integer. Instead it prints the value that I entered in `scanf`.
Can anyone explain the output?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    long x;
    float t;
    scanf("%f",&t);
    printf("%d\n",t);
    x=90;
    printf("%f\n",x);
    {
        x=1;
        printf("%f\n",x);
        {
            x=30;
            printf("%f\n",x);
        }
    x=9;
    printf("%f\n",x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, we can. But we won't as you're asking this question at the wrong place. Please ask this on CodeReview instead.

Comment: have you looked up the documentation for the functions that are being used? What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  However you are using a floating point format to print out a long variable and that will not work correctly.  Use %d rather than %f when printing x.

Comment: Take a look on a printf flags. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @H2CO3 No, [codereview.se] only does reviews of code with no known bugs. This question would be off-topic on [codereview.se], but it is on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

`t` has type `float`, so `printf("%d\n",t)` invokes **undefined behaviour**, since `%d` expects an argument of type `int`. Anything can happen. (The same is true of `printf("%f\n",x)`: `%f` expects a `double`, but the type of `x` is `long int`.)

I once answered one of those cases [in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295097/596781); perhaps that's of some interest. The upshot is that in practice you can explain the observed behaviour by studying the anatomy of IEEE754 floating point numbers, and by knowing the sizes of integral types on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `%d` when printing an `int` variable, like this:

```
printf("%ld", x);
```

You are using `%f`.

Comment: I would say printf("%ld", x);

Comment: Since it is long, yes, you are correct. Thanks for the clarification! Will update.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> printf("%f\n",x);
> ```

`x` has the type `long`, but the `%f` converter expects a floating-point value (of type `double`). Normally, when you pass an integer to a function that expects a floating-point value, the value is silently converted. However, this only applies to functions with a fixed number of arguments and a prototype indicating what the type of each argument is. It does not apply to variadic functions such as `printf`, because the compiler doesn't have enough information to know what to convert the value to: the format string may only be analyzed at runtime.

The language specification leaves the behavior of this program undefined: it can do anything. What is probably happening in this case is that `x` is stored in some integer register, and `f` is stored in some floating-point register. Since the `printf` calls are looking for a floating-point value, the compiled code goes to look in the first floating-point register. If you had passed a floating-point value to `printf`, the argument would end up in that register. But you didn't, so the value in that register was the last value that was stored there: the value read by `scanf`.

A good compiler would warn you that you're doing something wrong. For example, here's what I get when I compile your code with `gcc -O -Wall`:

```
a.c:2: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'
a.c: In function 'main':
a.c:7: warning: format '%d' expects type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double'
a.c:9: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'long int'
a.c:12: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'long int'
a.c:15: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'long int'
a.c:18: warning: format '%f' expects type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'long int'
```

I recommend configuring your compiler to print such warnings and paying attention to them.

To make your program work, either pass a floating-point value where one is expected, or tell `printf` to expect an integer value. Either

```
printf("%f", (double)x);
```

or

```
printf("%ld", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

x is a long integer yet you're printing it as a float.  And t is a float yet you're printing it as an integer.  Switch the %d and %f format specifiers in your printf calls.