# memcpy doesn't copy anything or not?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010

I don't understand why the array t1 is empty. As I know, memcpy shouldn't care about the underlying types of the objects. What do you think? %)

```
cout << sizeof(float) << sizeof(int) << endl;

float *t1= (float *)malloc(20*sizeof(float));
memset(t1,0x00,20*sizeof(float)); 

int *t2= (int *)malloc(20*sizeof(int));
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) 
    t2[i]=i;  

memcpy(t1,t2,20*sizeof(int));

for (int i=0; i<20; i++) 
    printf("%f\t", (float)t1[i]);
```

I know what type casting means. Ok I did a little mistakes. It was carelessness!

**P.S. It was sample for understanding  how  memcpy works!!**

Comment: You've tagged this as "C", yet you're using `cout`?

Comment: sorry, it is mix code ))

Comment: The final `(float)` cast is completely pointless: variable function arguments are default-promoted. (And `t1[i]` is *already* of type `float`!) Are you copy/pasting bits of code from somewhere else?

Comment: I know what type casting means. Ok I did a little mistakes. It was carelessness!! And now my reputation is down. It's wonderful. Thank you all.

Comment: The only question I can actually see here is 'What do you think?', a very poor question I am sure we can all agree. That aside, you are using a painful mixture of bad C code and bad C++ code. You Have not even taken the time to explain what result you are getting an what you expected to get.

Comment: >You Have not even taken the time to explain what result you are getting an what you expected to get
It isn't obvious to you?

Comment: @Leila, Your Title is completely wrong. You may get down votes because of that (i'm not a down voter :) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is not "empty", despite your protestations. It just holds a very, very small value: Your machine uses the IEEE754 standard for representing floating points. In that standard, the word with all zeros represents the value 0.0. The next bigger word (i.e. the one obtained by adding 1 to the underlying bits) represents the next biggest floating point value, which is an extremely tiny, denormal value. When you `printf` this value to standard precision (6 decimal places?), it's just rounded to zero.

Here's a [tangentially related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295097/596781) of mine on a similar question.

Comment: I see that you are right. I can see these small values with cout << t1[i];

Comment: Totally nitpicky point: the latest revision of IEEE 754 (2008) changed "denormal" to "subnormal".

Comment: @PeteBecker: Haha, interesting :-)

Answer (score 4):

The function `memcpy` copies bits, **verbatim**. So you're copying bits from an integer array to a float array: there's very little chance the contents will match the floating point representation.  So you get an array filled with stuff that makes little sense to your floating point format.

In a nutshell, at the lowest level, `1` and `1.0f` look wildly different.

---

The cast `(float)t1[i])` doesn't really do anything since `t1[i]` is already `float`.

Comment: Ok. So memcpy is useful function

Comment: @Leila if it was useless, I don't think it would exist.

Comment: @Leila It's not useless, it's made for other uses :-)

Comment: @cnicutar Just a nit, but you're "there is no chance" isn't quite right.  It's undefined behavior, and there is actually one architecture where it works.  (One of the Unisys mainframes, so I seriously doubt that the OP is using it.)

Comment: @cnicutar Not that it's really relevant to the OP: since the question is also tagged Visual Studios, we know he's not working on a Unisys mainframe.

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing the integer values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .. 20 into floats. Floats and ints use different underlying representations, and offhand, I think those values are just very very small and will print as 0 unless you change the format to include a lot of precision.

Answer (score 1):

Bit arrangement is different in an int and a float.Even if things get copied well you wont be able to understand it.

Change to

```
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) 
  printf("%d\t", (int)t1[i]);
```

and you will see things copied.

Answer (score 0):

memcpy copies memory as bytes and doesn't care what underlying types have been stored at the memory location. Integers in memory are stored in a different format than floats so what basically ends up in t1 could be but must not necessarily be valid floating point values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++ you can use the C++ features instead, like `std::vector`

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << sizeof(float) << sizeof(int) << endl;
    std::vector<float> floatVector;
    std::vector<int> intVector;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        intVector.push_back(i);
    }
    floatVector.resize(intVector.size());

    std::copy(intVector.begin(), intVector.end(), floatVector.begin());
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cout << "element[" << i << "]: " << floatVector[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good. But I use Memory_alloc from c6accel library (sharing memory with DSP). I can't represent this data with vector object.