# why is the output of the following code coming to be zero?

Tags: c, printf, addition, output

```
main()
{
    float a=10;
    float c;
    float b=5.5;
    c=a+b;
    printf("%d",c);
}
```

The output of the above code is zero.Why is that? I am sorry if that is some really simple C concept, I am kind of a beginner.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. You're lying to the compiler. (I once answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7295097/596781).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `%f` (or `%e` or `%g`, depending on your preferred format) instead of `%d` for floating-point numbers. Indeed, using `%d` for non-integers is "undefined behaviour".

```
printf("%f", c);
```

Alternatively, if you're trying to round the floating-point to an integer, you must cast it first.

```
printf("%d", (int) c);
```

Comment: Or in the unlikely case he's trying to round the number to an int: printf("%d", (int)c);

Comment: @user814064 Right, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See `a+b=c` will result c to become 15.5
when you try to printf c as a decimal "%d" it will be "undefined behaviour" as Chris said.
If you do `printf("%d",(int)c);` your out put will become 15 and if you `printf("%f",c);` you will get 15.5