# Why printf() isn't outputting this integer as float number?

Tags: c, windows, printf, stdio

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 12345;
    printf("%f", i);

    return 0;
}
```

printf() will output 0.000000, shouldn't printf() interpret the bits contained in `i` as a float number?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7295066/596781

Comment: Then printf should not ask for %f, %i, isn't it?

Comment: In non-technical language, you're saying `give me an egg` while you're expecting to get `chicken soup`. :-) `%f` is for float, `%i` is for integer. There is no auto-type check of supplied variable.

Comment: Enable all warnings in your compiler. If using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you would have been warned by a recent  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: If you want the integer to be interpreted as a float, you'll need to cast it (or rather, cast the pointer); in which case, all bets are off.

Answer (score 7):

This is technically undefined behaviour, so anything can happen, for instance what @Art describes in his answer.

This answer here is therefore an explanation as to what would happen if you tried to print 12345 as a float assuming printf indeed sees the correct 32-bit value.

Let's analyze the binary representation for the number you are trying to represent.

Using http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html we can see that the decimal number `12345` has the following 32-bit representation:

```
decimal      12345
hexadecimal  0x00003039
```

Converted bit-to-bit to a IEEE-754 floating point 32-bit value, this represents:

```
float        1.7299E-41
```

let's try to print it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%f\n", 1.7299E-41);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
0.000000
```

Now let's read `printf` man page, as found here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

> f, F
>
> The double argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd, where the number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the precision specification. If the precision is missing, it is taken as 6; if the precision is explicitly zero, no decimal-point character appears. If a decimal point appears, at least one digit appears before it.

The `1.7299E-41` value cannot be represented using this flag with the default precision, so the result you get is indeed the correct value.

Comment: Good argument, but try this with a different int and you'll still get 0. I'm pretty sure this is not the real reason.

Comment: Seems like my demonstration is indeed fallacious, I think invoking UB is, while much shorter, the correct answer here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer is the correct one (it is if my assumption about x86_64 holds). But yes, UB is the only strictly correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Technically this is **undefined behaviour**.

You should use a union to do this and print it with `%e` instead of `%f`, because it is a small number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
union int2float
{
  int a;
  float b;
};

int main()
{
    union int2float tmp;
    tmp.a = 12345;

    printf("%e\n", tmp.b);

    return 0;
}
```

This results in `1.729903e-41`.

with `%.100f` you will get `0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000172990295420898667405534417057140146406548336724655872023410` as output.

Comment: Note that C99 introduced `%a` (`%A`) format specifier, that allows to print an number as hexadecimal floating-point number (here `0x1.81c8p-136`). One advantage of it is that it prints number just as it's stored in binary format (assuming common IEEE-754 format with base-2 floating-point number, i.e. with mantissa and exponent), rather than in decimal aproximation.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason `printf` doesn't interpret the bits in `i` as a floating point number is that `printf` doesn't see `i` at all. I suspect you're running x86_64 or a similar platform where the arguments are passed to functions in registers. Normally `printf` would interpret your int as whatever format specifier you gave it. But floating point arguments to functions are handled differently on x86_64 and are put into different registers. So the reason you get 0 as output is that `printf` pulls out the first floating point argument after the format string instead of the first general purpose register and prints that. Since you haven't used any floating point registers before your call to `printf` they are most likely zeroed from program start.

Here's an experiment you can try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("%f\n", 17.42);
        printf("%f\n", 0x87654321);
        return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
$ ./foo
17.420000
17.420000
```

Having said all that, the only correct answer is: this is undefined behavior, don't do this. But it's interesting to see what's going on under the hood.

If you want to dive into this and are running on Linux/MacOS/*BSD [this document, section 3.2.3](http://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) describes how arguments are passed to functions (including varargs functions like printf). Windows does things slightly differently, but in this case the result on Windows would be exactly the same. `printf` on Linux/MacOS/*BSD would expect the argument to be printed in `%xmm0` (`%xmm1` on Windows) while your call passes it in `%rsi` (`%rdx` on Windows).

Of course, if I'm wrong about x86_64, disregard everything I said and look at the answer from @SirDarius, because that applies to many (especially older) architectures. If you're on an alpha, sparc, powerpc, arm, etc. you're on your own. Call `printf` once with an int, once with a float, disassemble the compiled code and see how arguments are passed.

Comment: I have to +1 this. However for some reason, I get 17.420000 followed by 17.420006 with the exact same code (gcc (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.8.1) 64-bit.

Comment: @SirDarius Probably because the printf implementation touches the floating point registers in a way that doesn't preserve them. My example code gives you not just one, but two undefined behaviors for the price of one.

Comment: ah, my bad, the GCC was 32-bit. The 64-bit version outputs 17.420000 and 0.000000. UBfest it is :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print an int as float, cast it:

```
printf("%f", (float)i);
```

Comment: I imagine he rather expected the result of `printf("%f", *((float*)&i))`. At least that's what I took from "interpret the bits contained in i as a float number". And this answer does not explain why that isn't what he got.

Answer (score 1):

The only way `printf()` knows the data-type of the arguments after the formatting string (and their count) is by reading the format string. The representation of an integer in memory is different from a floating point number. You pass printf() data in the format of an integer number but it assumes the format of a floating point number. This is why you get garbage in the console. You can correct this by type-casting.

```
printf("%f", (float) i);
```

Comment: Except he didn't get garbage, he got 0. He expected garbage (or rather the bits of the int being interpreted as a float) and he's asking why that isn't what he got.

Comment: @sepp2k You're right, I misread the question in that part. I got when I tried the OPs snippet.

Answer (score 0):

when you use the `%f` format specifier you have to use the float variable and print the value.
but you have declared `i` as integer and trying to print using `%f` it will print some value.
As it is a integer you have to use `%d` specifier.
In `printf %f` will search for the float variable. but there will be no float variable, so it prints some value.

You can type cast the integer value while printing.
`printf("%f",(float)i);`

Answer (score 0):

To make `i` as `float` type you need to do type cast.

You can use

```
printf("%f", (float)i);
```

Example.

```
float myFloat;
int myInt; 
myFloat = (float)myInt ;        // Type casting
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int i = 12345;
printf("%.2f", i/1.0f);
```